# How to encode XML to JSON including the root element?

Tags: php, xml, json

Let's say I have a XML document

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<book>
<title>Book Title</title>
<isbn>123456789</isbn>
</book>
```

And I want to convert this XML document into a JSON string

```
<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_file('book.xml');
//print '{"book":';
    print json_encode($xml, true);
//print '}';
?>
```

But this excludes the root element, 'book.'

Why does json_encode exclude the root element?

Answer (score 0):

I think [Zend Json Library](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.json.xml2json.html) has an option to include the root.

```
$jsonContents = Zend_Json::fromXml($xmlStringContents, true);
```

The true will cause the root to be displayed in the JSON object.  Not Sure if this can be done with simplexml_load_file aad print json_encode($xml, true);